# node.js - how to recognize invalid UTF-8?

Tags: node.js, unicode, utf-8

I'm implementing support of UTF-8 and I'm facing an issue. I'd like to error out on receiving invalid UTF-8. Okay:

```
var utf8 = require('utf8');

try {
    var result = utf8.decode(req.params.container);
    console.log('a valid utf8 (from ', req.params.container , '): ', result);
    self.bucket_name = req.params.container;
    next();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Invalid UTF-8 (', req.params.container, '): ', e);
    res.statusCode = 412;
    res.end('Invalid UTF8 or contains NULL');
} finally {
    ;
}
```

And then it says that this unicode string is invalid: 嘈嘈Ωऀ鐌鐌㜄鐊툏㜃댋ं蔈㜅

But some python libraries say that this string is valid unicode. So my question is two-fold: (1) is that valid UTF-8, and (2) how do I actually determine if a string is or is not valid utf-8, in node.js?

Comment: If you already have a string, it's too late to tell whether it's invalid.  You're completely misunderstanding that function.

Comment: @SLaks: I can have an invalid UTF-8 string, for example: ������

Comment: No; that's a regular string containing REPLACEMENT CHARACTERs.  Invalid UTF8means invalid bytes, not a string.

Comment: @SLaks: A single high surrogate character is invalid (uninterpretable, untranslatable, undecodable) UTF-8, without having invalid UTF-8 bytes. Thank you for trolling. If you don't have an answer, you can just skip a question, you know?

Comment: Whatever decoded the bytes into Unicode character should (I believe) replace imbalanced surrogates with REPLACEMENT CHARACTERs during decoding.

Comment: If `params.container` contains utf-16 characters (like `嘈嘈Ωऀ鐌`) why you need to decode it? Or it can contain both utf-16 or byte chars, and you need some heuristic algorithm?

Comment: Sorry, it's been so long I have little info on the project. I think I needed to not decode, but specifically find invalid strings (a negative test). I think I needed to throw a specific, rather than generic, error on a null character or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I capture utf-8 decode errors in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006799/how-do-i-capture-utf-8-decode-errors-in-node-js)