# Why redis returns a [239, 191, 189] response buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm using redis to stores a bitfield data and I set a u4 value in on each offset.
I need to get the buffer in Nodejs server.
for **0-7**,redis returns the correct buffer.
But when setting **8-15** value.It returns a strange buffer.Uint8Array views into the buffer and it shows **[239,191,189]** which represents messy code.
here is the copy-to-run test code.
btw problem ocurrs with the resoponse buffer.Trying to get the #0 value is ok.

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const redis = require('redis'),
      RDS_PORT = 6379,
      RDS_HOST = '139.199.33.69',//139.199.33.69
      RDS_OPTS = {detect_buffers: true},
      client = redis.createClient(RDS_PORT, RDS_HOST, RDS_OPTS);
console.log('redis ready')
const canvas_name = 'canvas-bitfield';
client.del(canvas_name)
client.send_command("bitfield",[canvas_name,'SET','u4','#0',10,'OVERFLOW','FAIL'])

client.send_command('bitfield',[canvas_name,'GET','u4',0],redis.print) //reply:10

client.get(canvas_name,function(err, reply){
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    const buff = Buffer.from(reply.toString());
    const view8 = new Uint8Array(buff); 
    console.log(view8) //Uint8Array(3) [239, 191, 189]
})
```

Comment: This is unrelated but I'll point it out anyway: send_command is *asynchronous*. So you should use the callback parameter to ensure that any subsequent commands are executed after the send_command has genuinely finished: `client.send_command(command, args, callback)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why redis returns a [239, 191, 189] response buffer?

Notice here that `reply` is a `String` not a `Buffer`! *Why?* Well you are using `detect_buffers: true`. From the documentation of the `redis` package, with this option set to true, the type of `reply` depends on the type of the first argument passed to `client.get()`. Since you passed it a *String* (`canvas_name` is a String), the value of reply is also a *String*:

```
client.get(canvas_name,function(err, reply){
    console.log(typeof reply) // => String
    // ...
```

For this to work, the `redis` package [internally](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/565080667861629d778dd3e73bfa4f0010df8b38/lib/utils.js#L19) makes the function call of: `Buffer.toString()` to convert your Buffer of `<Buffer a0>` to a String, and will then pass this String to the callback; binding to `reply`. The problem is that [`Buffer.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end), without any arguments passed, will attempt to decode the buffer using UTF-8 but `<Buffer a0>` is not a valid UTF-8 string! Node.js in this case [silently fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006799/how-do-i-capture-utf-8-decode-errors-in-node-js) and returns U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. Hence `reply` is a String containing just one character of U+FFFD or 65533.

```
client.get(canvas_name,function(err, reply){
    console.log(reply.length); // 1
    console.log(reply.charCodeAt(0)) // => 65533
    // ...
```

This number (65533) comes from **redis (Node.js) failing to parse your buffer as a UTF-8 string**! From there, you put 65533 into a Buffer and create a Uint8Array, of `[239, 191, 189]`:

```
console.log(Buffer.from("\uFFFD")) // => <Buffer ef bf bd>
console.log(new Uint8Array(Buffer.from("\uFFFD"))); // => Uint8Array(3) [239, 191, 189]
```

---

To quickly fix for your problem, you need to tell the `redis` package to not convert
the buffer to a String. Instead get the buffer directly:

```
client.get(new Buffer(canvas_name), function(err, reply) {
    console.log(typeof reply) // => Buffer
    console.log(reply) // => <Buffer a0>
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    const view8 = new Uint8Array(reply);
    console.log(view8) // => Uint8Array(3) [160]
});
```

*Note: A buffer with decimal values in the range 0-7 will successfully be decoded as a UTF-8 string which is why you coincidentally got the correct buffer.*

Comment: THANK YOU! I finally solve this with a {return_buffers:true} option to redis.

Comment: Great! Please accept this answer if you found it useful.